# Root PID of Docker container

Tags: pid, docker, lxc

How can I find the external PID of the root PID inside a Docker container - that is, the one that has PID 1 inside the container? `docker ps` doesn't seem to display that information.

Comment: As of April 2014, Docker has changed how it starts containers and the below solutions no longer work.

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824759/root-pid-of-docker-container#25243464) seems to work on more recent versions.

Answer (score 9):

One possible way is:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }}' $CONTAINER_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' $(docker ps -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a POSIX shell function that captures the PID for a given container.

```
pid_for_container() {
  ps -C lxc-start -o pid= -o args= | fgrep -- " -n $1" | cut -d' ' -f1
}
```

It is a minimal (I hope) pipeline for this purpose, using the cheapest possible (`fgrep` instead of `grep`, `cut` instead of `awk`) commands.